# Add/Remove a control from another Form - C#

Tags: c#, winforms

How to Add or Remove a control from another form that is active and currently showing? I am using the following code:

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
        frm1.Controls.RemoveByKey("button1");
    }
```

But it is not working because of new initialization of Form1.

Comment: works fine for me. Perhaps post more of the code to figure out where the problem is.

Comment: Make sure "button1" is not inside another container, like a panel or a groupbox.  Also, frm1 is not active and is not showing in the current example.

Comment: @LarsTech - The form1 is opened and I want to remove the control from it at runtime.

Comment: But you are make a `new Form1()`.  If Button2 is trying to remove Button1 on the same form, try getting rid of frm1 line and just use `this.Controls.RemoveByKey("button1");` since `this` would reference your current form.

Comment: @LarsTech - Button2 is on Form2 whereas Button1 is on Form1. As I mentioned on the title I want to do the action from a Form to another Form.

Answer (score 1):

If the form, from which a control is to be removed, is a child of another form you can access the form through the OwnedForms property. And after accessing it, you can remove controls from it. For example

**Form1**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var form = new Form3 { Owner = this };
    form.Show();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(OwnedForms.Length > 0)
    {
        var form = OwnedForms[0];
        //assuming there's a control with id 'One':
        form.Controls.RemoveByKey("One"); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the comments, it is clear that Form2 does not have a reference to Form1.

You didn't post any code on how you are displaying Form2, but here is an example on how it could work by passing the reference through the constructor:

```
public class Form2 : Form {
  private Form1 _Form1;

  public TestForm(Form1 form1) {
    InitializeComponent();
    _Form1 = form1;   // <- this is the reference from Form1
  }
}
```

Then your removing action on Form2 would look like this:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  _Form1.Controls.RemoveByKey("button1");
}
```

When creating Form2 from Form1, this is an example on how it would be passed:

```
private Form2 _Form2;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  _Form2 = new Form2(this);  // <- this is the reference of Form1 you are passing
  _Form2.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you already know you need the one instance of *Form1*.
If this is your main form and you used the Visual Studio wizard to create a *Windows Forms Application* you can look in the *Program* class. There is usually the main form built.
Now you need to assign the `new Form1()` expression to a variable and assign it to the second form with button *button2*.